# how do i test subprocess's stdout, stderr in python on windows

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> f = open('txt', 'w+')
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['dir'],stdout=f,stderr=f, shell=True)
>>> p.communicate()
(None, None) # stdout, stderr are empty. Same happens if I open a win32 gui app instead of python (don't think win32 gui apps set a stdout/stderr)
```

I want to retrieve the stdout or stderr of a `subprocess` to test a few characteristics of them (not the current `sys.__stdout__`). How can I do this from the python interpreter?

Comment: Do you want the output to the file or to python shell?

Comment: anywhere I can get a reference to the std objects! Just want to experiment with the object, and so far it's just a None ref...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE)

**Example**

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = True )
>>> process.communicate()
('file\nfile1\nfile2, '')
```

As it can be seen,

```
process.communicate()[0]
```

is the stdout of the command and

```
process.communicate()[1]
```

is the stderr

Comment: You don't need shell=True

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I copied that from them question :p

Comment: Actually just saw the OP is using windows so it would need shell=True and just pass the string dir or use `["cmd", "/c", "dir"]`, on linux using shell=True with a list of args would no work properly

Answer (score 2):

You can use check_output and catch a CalledProcessError:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

try:
    out = check_output(["dir"]) # windows  out = check_output(["cmd", "/c", "dir"])
except CalledProcessError as e:
    out = e.output

print(out)
```

Comment: Add `shell=True` on Windows (`dir` is an internal command) and pass the command as a string, not a list. To get subprocess' output, use `e.output`, not `e.message`. The latter includes other info too.